# Pythonic way to construct a Factory/Builder class pattern for smoothing a series

Tags: python, factory-pattern

I have a number of classes that implement smoothing techniques on a series of prices.

I am trying to figure the best way of implementing any of these smoothing classes within the `__call__` function of another class, where some operation is then performed on the smoothed series:

i.e.

```
class NoSmoother:
    def __init__(self, prices):
        self.prices = prices
    
    def __call__(self):
        return self.prices

class MASmoother:
    def __init__(self, prices):
        self.prices = prices
    
    def __call__(self, window):
        return self.prices.rolling(window).mean().to_frame("price")


class ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices():
    def __init__(self, prices):
        self.prices = prices

    def __call__(self, smoother=ma_smoother, window=3)
        smoothed_prices = SomeBuilderClassThatCallsTheCorrectSmootherClass()
```

As you can see, I would need the factory/builder class to implement `NoSmoother` if say smoother = None, otherwise, it would call the appropriate smoothing class. Of course, the returned object can vary from simple to complex, for example, if I smooth the prices using a Kalman Filter, the class can expect many more parameters.

Currently, my code instantiates `class ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices()` with a price series, then calls by passing a **config.

Desired Output:

Ideally, I would like to be able to call any smoothing class from within the call function of

`class ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices()`.

Example implementation:

```
configs = {'smoother': MASmoother, 'window': 3}

processor = ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices(prices)

output = processor(**config)
```

My attempt:

```
class Smoother:
    def __init__(self, prices):
        self.prices = prices
    
    def __call__(self, smoother, *args, **kwargs):
        return partial(smoother, **kwargs)
      
    def ma_smoother(self, window: int = 3):
        return self.prices.rolling(window).mean().to_frame("price")
        
    def no_smoother(self):
        return self.prices

class ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices:
    def __init__(self, prices):
        self.prices = prices
    
    def __call__(self, smooth_method = 'no_smoother'):
        smoother = Smoother(prices)
        prices_smoothed = smoother(**configs)
        # do other things

if __name__ == '__main__':
   configs = {'smoother': 'ma_smoother', window=3}

   label = ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices(**configs)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd make these just functions, not classes...

Comment: What is going to determine which class to instantiate? Will that be known well ahead of time, or perhaps not until the call needs to take place?

Comment: @quamrana - when I call ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices(), I pass a config that determines the class to instantiate and it's parameters

Comment: Please update your post with all this calling and parameter passing you do. With python its easy to just write the code that you want to have and sort out the details later.

Comment: Ideally, the user will pass a config file to the execution of `ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices()` naming the smoothing method to be applied or none at all.

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a requirement that the class `ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices`, remains a class. What I had envisioned is some form of base class, with a lookup i.e NamedTuple that when called within `ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices` knows what smoother to apply? Hopefully I am making sense.

Comment: There is nothing you have shown us that requires `ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices` to be a class. It can simply be a factory function which returns the correct smoother.

Comment: the class, `ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices` takes the smoothed prices and creates labels off the back of these - it calls many different methods in order to construct the label i.e. it's purpose is associated with something quite different from simply smoothing the price.

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity, if you don't have a lot of state, I'd just use regular functions.

You can [use `functools.partial()` to partially apply a function](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functools.html#functools.partial), i.e. in this case set the MA window:

```
from functools import partial


def no_smoother(values):
    return values


def ma_smoother(values, *, window):
    return values.rolling(window).mean().to_frame("price")


def get_prices():
    ...


def get_smoothed_prices(smoother):
    prices = get_prices()
    return smoother(prices)


get_smoothed_prices(smoother=no_smoother)
get_smoothed_prices(smoother=partial(ma_smoother, window=3))
```

### EDIT

Based on the edit in the question:

```
configs = {'smoother': MASmoother, 'window': 3}
processor = ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices(prices)
output = processor(**config)
```

would be expressed as something like

```
def construct_smoother(smoother, **kwargs):
    return partial(smoother, **kwargs)

smoother = construct_smoother(**configs)
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Can you please show me how you would implement this in the call method of the class ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices()?

Comment: The equivalent of that class and method here is `get_smoothed_prices` itself; it gets the unsmoothed prices and applies a smoother. If you need something to construct a smoother with the given arguments... well, that's `partial()`.

Comment: @cmp Please see my edit - it might illuminate things.

Comment: Many thanks for this. The only problem I have is that I would like this will be used across a lot of different repos, and call from different modules. So for example, I would pass the config to the `___call__` method of `thatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices(prices)`, it would interpret the key and know which smoother to use, without having to import the smoother implementation locally (if that makes sense?) Would it be possible to show me how you would do so in a class please? I have added my attempt above.

Comment: You'd probably want a registry (dict) that would map smoothing names to their implementations. However, with that indirection, your users would need to know the (kw)args for each smoother; I assume `window` is only relevant for moving average here. In that sense, it would be a better API to just have your users pass in smoothing functions they've constructed. Another, higher-level API could work with a config dict.

Comment: Agree - this is what I envisioned, however, I was unsure of what to implement conventially in this regard? You are right insofar that the user already knows the names of the smoothers. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Given your latest update you need to pass in the `configs` as well:

```py
configs = {'smoother': MASmoother, 'window': 3}

processor = ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices(configs, prices)

output = processor(**config)
```

So that means `ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices` could be like this:

```py
def ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices(configs, prices):
    smoother = configs['smoother'](prices)
    return smoother
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a factory, you can create a class method inside a class.

```
# declaration
class Factory:
  # class variables (static)
  id = 0
  
  @classmethod
  def new(cls):
    return object()

# usage
obj = Factory.new()
```

If you have a class that needs arguments in the constructor, then you can pass variable number of arguments. Basically `*` removes brackets around the `list` or `dict` you are passing.

```
# declaration
def function(var1, var2, *args, **kwargs):
  # transfer variable arguments to other function
  return SomeObejct(*args, **kwargs)

# usage
obj = function(1, 2, a, b, c, key=value)
```

In your case, you would do something like this:

```
# declaration
# you can also pass classes as arguments
def __call__(self, smoother=MASmoother, window=3, *args, **kwargs)
    smoothed_prices = smoother(*args, **kwargs)
    return smoothed_prices

# usage
smth = ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices()
smoother1 = smth()
smoother2 = smth(NoSmoother, 2)
smoother3 = smth(NoSmoother, 2, arg1, arg2, key=value)
```

Comment: I don't get what this answer/code is trying to say. The ``class Factory`` seems bogus – the ``new`` constructor is plain wrong, and it's not clear at all why not to use the *regular* construction (``__new__``/`__init__`). The ``def function`` is – what exactly? Just an example for ``*args, **kwargs``? It doesn't help that the actual code relating to the question – the ``def __call__`` and `ThatDoesSomethingWithSmoothedPrices` – omits major parts such as the `class` *around* `def __call__` and adds bogus arguments that are discarded or erroneously forwarded.